# Has anyone used Bromium vSentry on their test machines?

Tags: security

My company wants to roll out Bromium vSentry to all their desktop and laptop machines. They tend not to distinguish between general office machines, and machines used for our testing.

Although I have no experience with the product, I'm concerned that it might interfere with my use of my machines as a tester. We use our machines for manual testing, and automated testing as well. We also have VMWare Player and Oracle VM VirtualBox installed on some machines.

Anyone have Bromium vSentry installed?
Any adverse side-effects I should know about?

Answer (score 1):

If all goes as planned you should not notice a thing, the goal is to be as seamless as possible.  With that said it all depends on how the administrator has configured the policy.  Your company should have included some sort of communications advising of potential impact.

BTW **Oracle Virtualbox and vSentry cannot coexist**, it will install but will not initialize/activate.

Comment: "Oracle Virtualbox and vSentry cannot coexist" thanks! Can you point out a source for this? Which will not activate - VirtualBox or Bromium?

Comment: Vendor statement and experience.  VirtualBox will not be impacted, vSentry will not be able to function with VirtualBox in place.